# i am getting an error on Desktopserver (Error 404) on my Localhost

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

i don't know to fix this error.after Restart database and xampp services for many times, i could find any solution.I could not access my local wordpress sites via Desktop server.
anyone know the reason please ?

Comment: Did you check xampp if apache and mysql is running?

Answer (score 0):

Try Wamp insted of xampp, after installing wamp

1. open myPhp Admin and create a Data base and username&Password
2. Locate wp-config.php (C:\wamp\www\wordpress)
3. Find Below coding (Line-23 to 29)

define('DB_NAME', '**Database Name**');  *(Enter database name )*

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '**DB User Name**'); *(Enter database username)*

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '**DB Password**');  *(Enter database password)*

4. Save it.

**Then install wordpress same as Xampp method.**

Answer (score 0):

My localhost page was also displaying as blank, or connection refused.  I had restarted the databases and confirmed port 80 was not being used by Skype.

Ultimately it was because port 443 was in use.  In this case I had VMWare Pro 14 occupying port 443.  Once I terminated the application I was able to access my sites through the Dekstop Server locahost page.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I used Desktop Server for years and loved it. I've been getting an "Access Denied" error on it. I switched to [Ampps](https://ampps.com/). Desktop Server used to be a good application, but I don't have time for errors straight on install.